# Mysql backup bug

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a SQL file created by mysqldump and suprisingly I get a SQL syntax error while running the backup file on the DB. How can it be possible considering that the file was created with mysqldump? BTW the SQL error is not very indicative.

Comment: are the source and destination server using same version of mysql? what are the options you used to dump the data? would you share the error?

Comment: It says there is an sql syntax error in an insert nothing very indicative. The backups untill now worked just fine and only in the last days started these issues. It worth noting that i changed a column in a huge table from text to medium text and that pretty much everything that changed

Comment: And yea its same version of mysql

Comment: Please post the *exact* error you get, omitting no details or punctuation.  Errors can be cryptic to the untrained eye and obvious to experienced DBAs, and there are easy ways to examine large files using `sed` or `perl` or other tools, but we need more info.  Also the output of `mysqldump -V` and the query `SELECT @@VERSION;`.

Comment: Output of mysqldump -V: ver 10.13 distrib 5.6.19 for linux. The error is just a syntax error while running the file, it happens after about 30-40 mins of queries running. I will provide the exact error Asap. The mysql version is 5.6.19

Answer (score 1):

I've seen things like those happening due to reserve words (keywords)... To allow them you need to use option `--allow-keywords` in your mysqldump command.

**Try:** `mysqldump --allow-keywords ...` with your complete command options.

If this doesn't fix, share the error.

**Update:**

You might like to consider differences in character-set and as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745815/sql-syntax-error-when-loading-mysqldump-file).

**Update-2:**

As you suggested that the error is not because of the reserve words, I'd ask you to check if that's the encoding issues as mentioned [here](http://nathan.rambeck.org/blog/1-preventing-encoding-issues-mysqldump).

To use the same backup file, considering the issue is with encoding, you can change it using following steps:

1. Find the encoding of a file:

`file -bi FILENAME`

2. If the file is not in utf8 and you want to convert it you do it as follows:

`iconv -f <source-encoding> -t utf8 FILENAME`

You may try using the dump now.

When you say "ERROR 1064: (42000)" or "error in your SQL syntax" it's synonymous, it still doesn't convey what's causing the error. Glad to know the security precautions you're following not to post anything other than mysql error name and numbers. Anyhow, please try above and share.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why did it only start to happen now and more importantly, there is any way to fix the bug backup? I need something out of it

Comment: This is a guess based on your description. Can you provide the exact error and at what syntax it's appearing?

Comment: It says sql syntax error after TABLE NAME read the manual.....

Comment: Did you try the suggestion? Is the table name a reserved word? There is an update on answer too... if that's the case.

Comment: Well i also thought it might be about encoding but why suddenly? Backups worked just fine untill now

Comment: If the backup size is not large enough would you mind reading it? Does it create errors if u only dump load single table ??

Comment: Thats the issue its too large to read, and the table name is not a reserved word. And i guess it might work if i dump a single table but eventually i need the whole db. Thank you very much for your help btw

Comment: Can you dump only single table and check? If the table is too large may be you can limit number of rows in mysqldump using `--where=pkid<100` or `where= true and limit 100`

Comment: Without checking exact error and syntax what's causing it, we cannot answer why-the-erroe

Comment: Its error 1064 (42000000). Anyway apart from fixing the backup, i really need to find a way to use the one which doesnt work. Any idea how i can do it? Thank you

Comment: @user69153 Please see Update-2 in the answer.

Comment: First of all, the file seems to be us-ascii encoded so basicly it should be the same as utf-8 doesnt it? I ran the command anyway and it threw an exception: iconv: ilegal input sequence at position 686.... Does it give us any lead? Thank you very much